# How to put the tensor product of two operators onto two variables?

Tags: tensors

I am trying to make an intuitive Mathemtaica program to show the principle of quantum  walking. The idea of quantum  walking is very simple and direct, but when I try to transfer it into  Mathemitca codes, I meet several difficulties.

The principle of quantum walk is introduced here http://susan-stepney.blogspot.jp/2014/02/mathjax.html and here http://xxx.tau.ac.il/abs/quant-ph/0303081

There are two operations in one step:

1. Coin operation (Hadamard coin H)
   [image]
2. Step operation (S)

[image]

With these two operations, bellow shows the first three steps of a quantum walk
[image]

I hope to express this process in an intuitive Mathematica codes.

The result of one step can be expressed as

[image]

The two operators,  H and S,  are put on these two variables

[image]

I do not know how to realize such a tensor product in Mathemcatica.

[image],

where S and H are two operators;  x and y are two variables; x is an array; y is an integer.

But I guess this equation is correct, because similar equation  is shown in wiki( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)

[image]

To realize this equation in Mathematica, I test  an example first, as shown below .

[image]

My expected  result is

[image]

But I cannot obtain this result.

My questions are:

1. How can I realize [image]  in Mathematica？
2. How to intuitively express the first three steps of quantum walk using Mathematica codes?

I have tried to solve this problem for several days, but made no progress. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated,

Comment: btw you can use latex syntax for equations.

Comment: @lalmei, Thank for you information! How to show latex in stackexchange? Do you have some tutorial link?

Comment: There is a "How to Format" on the right hand side when you edit your question. The link MathJax has all the information, but long story short, just type latex and it interprets automatically . e.g. \$\$<equation>\$\$ etc.

Comment: @lalmei, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your "quantum walk" states and operators as follows:

Represent the basis state in the form `state[spin, index]`, where `spin` is either `"↑"` or `"↓"`.

Define how the `H` and `S` operators act on basis states.

```
H[state[spin : ("↑" | "↓"), index_]] := 
  1/Sqrt[2] state["↑", index] + 
  1/Sqrt[2] If[spin == "↑", 1, -1] state["↓", index];

S[state[spin : ("↑" | "↓"), index_]] := 
  state[spin, index + If[spin == "↑", 1, -1]];
```

Define simplification rules for the operators, which reduces any operation to one in which operators act only on basis states.

```
H[u_ + v_] := H[u] + H[v];
S[u_ + v_] := S[u] + S[v];

H[u_?(FreeQ[#, state] &) v_] := u H[v];
S[u_?(FreeQ[#, state] &) v_] := u S[v];
```

Evaluate the random walk example at the top of your question.

```
state["↓", 0]
H[%]
S[%]
H[%]
S[%]
H[%]
S[%] // Simplify
```

I have used `Simplify` on the final result to rearrange it into a more concise form, which is

```
(-state["↓", -3] - 2 state["↓", -1] + 
  state["↓", 1] + state["↑", -1] + 
  state["↑", 3])/(2 Sqrt[2])
```

You can use the `Notation` package to make `state[spin, index]` display in a nicer way. For instance, after loading the `Notation` package, you could use the `Notation` palette to define the following notation

```
Notation[\[LeftBracketingBar]spin_〉⊗\[LeftBracketingBar]index_〉 ⟺ state[spin_,index_]]
```

and then re-evaluate the above random walk to obtain a "prettified" version of the output.

Comment: I have a further question: How to rearrange the element in an increasing order of  the “index”? e.g.,  (-state["\[DownArrow]", -3] - 2 state["\[DownArrow]", -1] + 
  state["\[DownArrow]", 1] + state["\[UpArrow]", -1] + 
  state["\[UpArrow]", 3])/(2 Sqrt[2]) is rearranged as  (-state["\[DownArrow]", -3] - 2 state["\[DownArrow]", -1] + 
   state["\[UpArrow]", -1] + state["\[DownArrow]", 1] + 
   state["\[UpArrow]", 3])/(2 Sqrt[2])

Comment: The easiest way to get the ordering you want is to define the basis state as `state[index, spin]` rather than `state[spin, index]`, and to correspondingly adjust the definitions of how the H and S operators act on these basis states. Don't forget to remove the old definitions first, or start with a fresh kernel. Mathematica will then automatically display the result ordered as you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I need to keep the form of state[spin,index], so as to show the original physical meaning. Would you please make a high-level program to rearrange the element? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can display the results in the form that you want by simply using the `Notation` package (that I mentioned in my answer above) to map each internal `state[index, spin]` expression to your required `state[spin, index]` displayed output. You then get the best of both worlds - convenient internal computations AND convenient displayed output - with the `Notation` package connecting the two of these together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good suggestion. I have succeesfully gotten the order I need.   Furthermore, I need to extract the coefficient of each term, so as to plot a figure of positions VS probabilities (probability= square of the coefficient). In the above example, the probability for position -1 is (-2/(2 Sqrt[2]))^2+(1/(2 Sqrt[2]))^2. Do you have some suggestions for picking up the coefficients?  I have tried several commands in Mathematica, but not succeed.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You use `Coefficient` to extract coefficients from expressions. So, using the `state[spin, index]` notation in my original answer, the probability of position -1 is `#.Conjugate[#]&[Coefficient[yourstate, {state["\[DownArrow]", -1], state["\[UpArrow]", -1]}]]`, where the pure function `#.Conjugate[#]&` computes this probability from the individual basis state amplitudes.

Comment: Thank you so much! This function is really useful.

Comment: Would you please help me on this new question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82778/how-to-summarize-the-coefficient-in-notation,  Thanks a lot!