# How to summarize the coefficient in Notation?

Tags: custom-notation

With the [help from Stephen Luttrell in stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58362/how-to-put-the-tensor-product-of-two-operators-onto-two-variables),  I can give an intuitive expression of quantum walk, as shown in the Mathematica codes below.

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "spin_"}], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}], 
   "\[CircleTimes]", 
RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "index_"}]}], 
 "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"state", "[", 
RowBox[{"spin_", ",", "index_"}], "]"}]]]
H[state[spin : ("\[UpArrow]" | "\[DownArrow]"), index_]] := 
1/Sqrt[2] state["\[UpArrow]", index] + 
1/Sqrt[2] If[spin == "\[UpArrow]", 1, -1] state["\[DownArrow]", 
 index];
S[state[spin : ("\[UpArrow]" | "\[DownArrow]"), index_]] := 
state[spin, index + If[spin == "\[UpArrow]", 1, -1]];
H[u_ + v_] := H[u] + H[v];
S[u_ + v_] := S[u] + S[v];
H[u_?(FreeQ[#, state] &) v_] := u H[v];
S[u_?(FreeQ[#, state] &) v_] := u S[v];
state["\[DownArrow]", 0]
H[%];
S[%];
H[%];
S[%];
H[%];
S[%];
H[%];
S[%] // Simplify
```

The result (the fourth step in quantum walk) is
[image]
Based on the previous codes, now I have a new problem :

First, I need to merge the  elements with the same    `\[LeftBracketingBar]index\[RightAngleBracket]`, 
  and rearrange the elements in an increasing order of   `\[LeftBracketingBar]index\[RightAngleBracket]`.
For example, in the fourth step, [image] should be merged and rearranged as[image]

Second, I need to summarize the coefficient  and calculate the intensity for 
each `\[LeftBracketingBar]index\[RightAngleBracket]`. The intensity is square of the coefficient of `\[LeftBracketingBar]"\[DownArrow]"\[RightAngleBracket]`, puls the   square of the coefficient of `\[LeftBracketingBar]"\[UpArrow]"\[RightAngleBracket]`. For example, in the fourth step, the intensity is

```
1/16 (1; 9 + 1; 1 + 1; 1 + 1; 1)=(1/16; 5/8; 1/8; 1/8; 1/16)
```

My final goal is to make the following table, which is the famous quantum walk table. The x axis is the position, and the y axis is the step number.
[image]

My question is how to summarize the coefficient in Notation using Mathematica codes? 
Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: any help ?  please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this problem, including redoing everything from the start, but let's begin with your last line by defining `ans = S[%] // Simplify`.

Define a rule for collecting together terms with the same index.

```
collect = 
  Plus[u___, a1_. state[spin1_, index_], v___, a2_. state[spin2_, index_], w___] :> 
  Plus[u, state[a1 spin1 + a2 spin2, index], v, w];
```

You can produce the collected & sorted states as follows:

Collect terms.

```
ans2 = ans //. collect
```

[image]

You should define some new `Notation` to display the spin part of a "collected" state in a more conventional way, but I won't do that here.

Sort terms.

```
ans2a = ans2 /. HoldPattern@Plus[x : state[__] ..] :> 
  Inactive[Plus] @@ SortBy[{x}, Last]
```

[image]

You have to use `Inactive[Plus]` rather than `Plus`, because `Plus` likes to sort its arguments.

You can produce the table of state probabilities as follows:

Collect terms.

```
ans3 = (ans // Expand) //. collect
```

[image]

Extract the probabilities.

```
ans3a = List @@ ans3 /. 
  a_. state[spinsum__, index_] :> 
    {spinsum /. b_. _String :> (a b)^2, index} // SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] &
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is really helpful to me!  Thank you very very much!